# Suggested edit notice is not visible in app inbox

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, ios-app

Someone suggested an edit for my post, and I saw this item in the inbox on the website:

> [image: web]

But not in the app:

> [image: app]

The unread (new) inbox item count is cleared already on the picture, but looks like the “suggested edit” item was counted for the app even though it was not visible. I.e., I saw 2 items indicator, but only one unread (with light blue background) message in my inbox.

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: Unknown (iPad7,3)
- OS Version: Version 11.2.1 (Build 15C153)

Comment: This also applies to notifications about posts being edited.